# How does this tungsten rod not short circuit the batteries?

Tags: power-supply

Why is the tungsten rod in [the following circuit](https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/projects/fd82758e7f8e4d97ac34da1a3701e2ce) not a short circuit?

[image: Schematic]

(Source: [digikey.com](https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/projects/fd82758e7f8e4d97ac34da1a3701e2ce))

I found it via [this video](https://youtu.be/wUdLlGLSQHQ?t=3m33s):

[image: Screengrab of the video]

(Source: [youtube.com](https://youtu.be/wUdLlGLSQHQ?t=3m33s))

I'm just very confused on how this works. It's a high current power supply, and he's running the positive on one side, and the negative on the other, which causes it to heat up.

What I don't understand is how it doesn't short circuit the batteries. Even if this is short circuiting them, would their be a way not to? We are only going to use a battery that is 9-12V with an amperage of 2-5.

Comment: You're going to have to draw current from the batteries to get power out of them to heat the wires/rods. You won't put more energy into the wires than you get out of the batteries.

Comment: Without more details on the circuit being used, I'm not sure I'm clear on what exactly you're asking (your second link just goes to a page that asks for my contact information --- a link to the schematic of the circuit would be more useful)

Comment: @ThePhoton
That's weird, I'll give you the link again. Try : https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/projects/fd82758e7f8e4d97ac34da1a3701e2ce
If that doesn't work:
https://www.digikey.com/schemeit/project/lightsaber-psu-2IB0EF0301C0/

Comment: It does look like a huge short to me. Point is that the total current divided by the number of batteries is less than the current they can apparently handle. Also, RC batteries may not come with overcurrent protection like smaller lipos do.

Comment: Can you edit the link where the video doesn't start on that loud beep lol? Really startled me :P

Answer (score 1):

The resistance of the rod prevents it being a short circuit.

Ohms Law tells you the resistance you need - if you're limited to 2A at 9V, that's 9/2 = 4.5 ohms. Just use a rod with that resistance.

Of course your heating is then limited to 18W, which may not be great YouTube material.

Answer (score 0):

Using a tungsten wire to heatup steel rods takes lots of energy.

Don't try this unless you are aware of the risks of battery warped plates exploding acid and other dangerous methods with LiPo batteries.

Active current trip sensing is a worthwhile venture or fusing.

(unless you are experienced as a trained Engineer.)

Basically when dealing with many kW of power, the resistance of the **load must be 99%** of the total loop with 1% ESR of the battery pack etc to accomplish dissipating only 1% of the total energy lost in the batteries and FETs.  ( The wiring and  FETS were possibly their weakest link in the video which caused a fire, which was a good thing, LiPo fires can be *life extinguishers.* by toxic fumes or explosions. Lead-acid explosions are just as bad.

**here the twisted iron rods have the most  resistance I believe 2~5 Ohms**  so technically a high current but not a 0V dead short.  Clamped wire contact oxidation on mild steel is the major cause.

Comment: We want to achieve something like they did in the video with a battery like this: http://www.be-electronics.com/product_p/ps1230.htm.

Comment: 45 milliohms and 10A max discharge current wont compare to the light saber video with 24VLipo's x16P not arcs but using steel as resistors with much more power avail.. and take note of fire. unless you want to be next in the Darwin Awards.

Comment: Shouln't that be the other way around? If the resistance of the load is 1% of the ESR of the batteries, 99% of the energy is dissipate in the batteries

Comment: @user253751  murphy's Law